# Make SQL query with loop in the Firebird

Tags: sql, select, inner-join, firebird, firebird2.5

I've been trying for a few days to build a SQL statement by extracting data from Firebird. I have two dependent tables. The list it obtains is not in the order it should be.

Example tables:

TECHNOLOGY

| ID | NAME |
| --- | --- |
| 118 | TECHNOLOGY1 |
| 2 | TECHNOLOGY2 |
| 114 | TECHNOLOGY3 |
| 57 | TECHNOLOGY4 |
| 115 | TECHNOLOGY5 |
| 81 | TECHNOLOGY6 |
| 87 | TECHNOLOGY7 |
| 95 | TECHNOLOGY8 |
| 98 | TECHNOLOGY9 |

TECHNOLOGY_INGREDIENTS

| ID | ID_POSITION | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 118 | TECHNOLOGY2 |
| 2 | 118 | TECHNOLOGY3 |
| 3 | 118 | ingredient1 |
| 4 | 2 | ingredient21 |
| 5 | 2 | ingerdient22 |
| 6 | 2 | ingredient23 |
| 7 | 114 | TECHNOLOGY4 |
| 8 | 114 | ingredient31 |
| 9 | 57 | ingredient41 |
| 10 | 57 | ingredient42 |

I wrote a SQL query that returns me the right result, but in the wrong order.

My query

```
select 
a.name as name_main, 
b.name as name_sub 
from
technology a
join technology_ingredients b
on a.id=b.id_position
```

I get result

| NAME_MAIN | NAME_SUB |
| --- | --- |
| TECHNOLOGY1 | TECHNOLOGY2 |
| TECHNOLOGY1 | TECHNOLOGY3 |
| TECHNOLOGY1 | ingredient1 |
| TECHNOLOGY2 | ingredient21 |
| TECHNOLOGY2 | ingerdient22 |
| TECHNOLOGY2 | ingredient23 |
| TECHNOLOGY3 | TECHNOLOGY4 |
| TECHNOLOGY3 | ingredient31 |
| TECHNOLOGY4 | ingredient41 |
| TECHNOLOGY4 | ingredient42 |

but I need result like this

| NAME_MAIN | NAME_SUB |
| --- | --- |
| TECHNOLOGY1 | TECHNOLOGY2 |
| TECHNOLOGY2 | ingredient21 |
| TECHNOLOGY2 | ingerdient22 |
| TECHNOLOGY2 | ingredient23 |
| TECHNOLOGY1 | TECHNOLOGY3 |
| TECHNOLOGY3 | TECHNOLOGY4 |
| TECHNOLOGY4 | ingredient41 |
| TECHNOLOGY4 | ingredient42 |
| TECHNOLOGY1 | ingredient1 |

In the result that I got from my query, you can see that join takes the first record from the first table, then compares it to all the entries in the second table, and so on.

As a result, what I expect, I need a query that will compare the first record from the first table and if the technology name in the second table is uppercase, then the next displayed record shows this technology with its ingredients.

I tried various queries, but unfortunately I failed to get the desired result. Is there a chance to execute such a query with this table structure, or should some more fields appear there?

The most important question is whether I can make a query that will return the result I need. There are no SQL procedures involved, because I display the query result in a ready tool in the application, in which I cannot call the procedure.

I do something like this, but it shows me null. I do not know why:

```
WITH RECURSIVE technology_upper_name(
    id, name) AS (
  SELECT a.ID, a.NAME FROM TECHNOLOGY a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT b.ID_POSITION, b.NAME FROM TECHNOLOGY_INGREDIENTS b 
  INNER JOIN technology_upper_name tun ON b.ID_POSITION = tun.id
)
SELECT id, name
FROM technology_upper_name
```

Comment: Please include the query you tried in your question.

Comment: I have already edited post. My SQL isn`t complicated. I wonder how to connect the first record, check that there is a technology uppercase and then look up the id in table 1 and associate it first with the ingredients corresponding to this technology. The link can be made by name, because in fact these names will match.

Comment: The idea is to show the ingredients of a given technology as soon as it appears in the second column. In the second table there is also an order column, but it determines the order of ingredients in a given technology and I do not know if it can be such an element after which the desired result could be obtained.

Comment: Hmm, I see now, maybe a recursive CT would allow for doing this, but I'm not sure, and I don't have time to experiment right now.

Comment: I understand, thanks anyway for your interest in the subject:)

Comment: I found something like this WITH [RECURSIVE] -- new keywords
CTE_A -- first table expression’s name
[(a1, a2, ...)] -- fields aliases, optional
AS ( SELECT ... ), -- table expression’s definition
CTE_B -- second table expression
[(b1, b2, ...)]
AS ( SELECT ... ),
...
SELECT ... -- main query, used both
FROM CTE_A, CTE_B, -- table expressions
TAB1, TAB2 -- and regular tables
WHERE ...

Comment: So, thanks for some advice Mark Rotteveel. When I implement this I will show solution.

Comment: Another way to do it is to use a stored procedure.

Comment: I know it, but i cannot use it. I wrote early that I have to get query because I run it in ready tool in app, which do not have option run like store procedure.

Answer (score 1):

SQL queries work on unordered sets. The fact that `select * from sometable` (e.g. `TECHNOLOGY` in your example) produces values in some order is an implementation detail. It can change with query conditions causing the optimizer to choose a different access plan, or table modifications like inserts, updates and deletes changing order of rows, or backups and restores, etc.

In other words, in general, the results you desire cannot be achieved without something that can be explicitly ordered on. Maybe it is possible to achieve this with Firebird 3.0 and higher window functions, but I'm not sure.